# Is there something needed to host/run a PHP file in ASP.NET 5?

Tags: php, asp.net, azure, asp.net-core

I've created an ASP.NET 5 project and everything you need has to be included as a dependency as part of the project file or bower or npm. I'm noticing that I can't seem to run/host any php files (which are there to support some legacy stuff) in the Azure cloud. Even though it's turned on. The file just comes back as 404.

I've been troubleshooting why Azure can't host the file and then thought that I probably need to include some dependency that was there before.

my **project.json**

```
{
  "version": "1.0.0-*",
  "compilationOptions": {
    "emitEntryPoint": true
  },

  "dependencies": {
    "Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.AspNet": "1.0.0-beta8",
    "Microsoft.AspNet.Server.Kestrel": "1.0.0-rc1-final",
    "Microsoft.AspNet.StaticFiles": "1.0.0-rc1-final",
    "Microsoft.AspNet.IISPlatformHandler": "1.0.0-rc1-final"

  },

  "commands": {
    "web": "Microsoft.AspNet.Server.Kestrel"
  },

  "frameworks": {
    "dnx451": { },
    "dnxcore50": { }
  },

  "exclude": [
    "wwwroot",
    "node_modules"
  ],
  "publishExclude": [
    "**.user",
    "**.vspscc"
  ]
}
```

my **startup.cs**

```
 public class Startup
    {
        // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to add services to the container.
        // For more information on how to configure your application, visit http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=398940
        public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
        }

        // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to configure the HTTP request pipeline.
        public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app)
        {
            app.UseIISPlatformHandler();
            app.UseDefaultFiles();
            app.UseStaticFiles();
        }

        // Entry point for the application.
        public static void Main(string[] args) => WebApplication.Run<Startup>(args);
    }
```

Could anyone confirm this and if so, what do I need to include?

**Update:** It's def not an "Azure" issue. I deleted all the files in the site via ftp and just uploaded the plain html and php files and it works. It's something related to publishing an asp.net 5 site.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot compile and serve PHP files directly from the ASP.NET 5 pipeline and AFAIK Azure WebSites only support a single server type per site instance.

You could serve the *content* of the PHP file using the static files middleware but I'm sure that's not what you want.

You need at least two servers. Either IIS or Kestrel for ASP.NET, and Apache (or something else?) for PHP. Then you have to configure one of the servers to act as a reverse proxy for the other for certain requests.

For example, let's say you have Apache listening on `localhost:80` and IIS listening on `localhost:81`. Then you can make Apache accept all the requests from outside and forward any request that doesn't end in `.php` to `localhost:81`.

Comment: Ouch! Sounds like a pain. Currently on IIS I can host up .net and php together. Are there plans to handles this in the future?

Comment: You can probably configure the web.config entry to point .php files to a specific handler instead of the http platform handler.